# Enterprise Architect C++ import fails with pointer to type

Tags: c++, import, enterprise-architect

Importing a C++ file, I find a function fails to parse when appearing as:

```
void Func(uint16_t *start){}
```

but passes with

```
void Func(uint16_t startIdx){}
```

Note that a pointer to int (int *) does parse correctly.  uint16_t has been added as a language macro definition in EA but that didn't help.  This seems somewhat routine, but any insight into the resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: How is `uint16_t` defined exactly Since you mention that it is "macro" it may expand to something funny. Also, there is a change in the name of the argument: in a place using macros I could imagine that `start` happens to be a macro, too...